SwiftUI List alignment
Why is the default alignment of a SwiftUI List so wacky? How do I get the text to left align?

My current code:
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    VStack {
                        Text(user.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(user.description)
                    }
            }
        }
            .navigationTitle("Profiles")
        }


You need to align the VStack

It's because of the VStack alignment, not the List. The default value is .center:

@inlinable public init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)

VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    ...
}

